# Assign Short Cut Key to a button in WPF

Tags: wpf, c#-3.0

How to assign short-cut key to a button in WPF?

Googling gave me the answer as to append _ instead of '&' in standard Winforms.

So after I have done  as below :

```
<Button Name="btnHelp" Content="_Help"></Button>
```

I did not find 'H' underlined.

That is first issue.

Second issue is that, how to execute that after pressing Alt + H at run-time. Say just to display a message box is sufficient for the example sake.

I am using C#, WPF

Thanks.

Comment: Underlining is only visible when pressing down ALT.

Answer (score 62):

This is kind of old, but I ran into the same issue today.
I found that the simplest solution is to just use an AccessText element for the button's content.

```
<Button Command="{Binding SomeCommand}">
    <AccessText>_Help</AccessText>
</Button>
```

When you press the *Alt* key, the 'H' will be underlined on the button.
When you press the key combination *Alt+H*, the command that is bound to the button will be executed.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/49c0e8e9-07ac-4371-b21c-3b30abf85e0b/button-hotkeys?forum=wpf

Comment: Exactly why one should always feel free to do a little "necromancing" here on SO. I find your solution very elegant. Thank you.

Comment: A little late to the party, but `<Button Content="_Help" .../>` also does the trick.

Comment: @MikeEason It's been a while since I wrote this answer, and I agree with you entirely. Either way works exactly the same, and the decision is up to the user. The MSDN page for [AccessText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.accesstext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#exampleToggle) has an example that shows using either method.

Comment: This approach also resolved my loss of the shortcut key when I switched over to using a Window specific Style Resource for setting the appearance of the buttons that previously set the button text inside the <Button></Button> tags with the underscore prefix.  Thank you.

Answer (score 49):

Solution for key binding (+ button binding) with own commands:

The body of XAML file:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <RoutedUICommand x:Key="MyCommand1" Text="Text" />
    <RoutedUICommand x:Key="MyCommand2" Text="Another Text" />
</Window.Resources>

<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="{StaticResource MyCommand1}" 
                    Executed="FirstMethod" />
    <CommandBinding Command="{StaticResource MyCommand2}" 
                    Executed="SecondMethod" />
</Window.CommandBindings>

<Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Key="Z" Modifiers="Ctrl" Command="{StaticResource MyCommand1}" />
    <KeyBinding Key="H" Modifiers="Alt" Command="{StaticResource MyCommand2}" />
</Window.InputBindings>

<Grid>
    <Button x:Name="btn1" Command="{StaticResource MyCommand1}" Content="Click me" />
    <Button x:Name="btn2" Command="{StaticResource MyCommand2}" Content="Click me" />
</Grid>
```

and .CS file:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public void FirstMethod(Object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // btn1
    }

    public void SecondMethod(Object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // btn2
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks... but... I don't suppose this could be done without having to edit the XAML in four different places every time one wants a single keyboard shortcut?

Comment: Just to save someone else some pain - make sure the `Window.Resources` comes BEFORE the `Window.CommandBindings/InputBindings`.  Otherwise, you will definitely run into a runtime problem about it not being able to find the resource.

Comment: All I needed here was the `<Window.InputBindings>` section, and bound each `KeyBinding` to an `ICommand` property in my view model.

Comment: The answer was written with the assumption that MVVM pattern is not used at all.

Answer (score 4):

The shortcut is just h for your sample code. On

To initially show underlines for shortcuts is a Windows setting and not controlled by an app. In Windows XP, go to Display Properties -> Appearance -> Effects and you will see a checkbox labeled "Hide underlined letters for keyboard navigation until I press the Alt key". For Vista/Win7 I think they moved that setting somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

To bind *keyboard gestures,* you need to use the *KeyGestures* with **commands**. Check out [commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx) for more information on this. Also there are loads of predefined commands which can directly be used in your application (like, Cut, Copy, Paste, Help, Properties, etc.,).

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution I've found is to stick a label inside the button:

```
<Button Name="btnHelp"><Label>_Help</Label></Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of old, but I ran into the same issue today.
I found that the simplest solution is to just use an hidden element for the shortcut key.

```
<Button x:Name="b2" Click="Button_Click">
    <Button.Content>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Width="0" Height="0">_H</Label>
            <TextBlock>
                <Underline>H</Underline>elp
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Window.InputBinding if you are using commands like me (For MVVM).

```
<Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="S"
                    Modifiers="Ctrl"
                    Command="{Binding TimeLogSaveCommand}" />

        <KeyBinding Key="V"
                    Modifiers="Ctrl"
                    Command="{Binding TimeLogCommand}" /> 
</Window.InputBindings>
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I was binding the button content and adding the "_" in the property just resulted in "_Do X" instead of the actual shortcut.
@jhenninger answer solved my issue.

```
<AccessText Text="{Binding LogButtonContent, FallbackValue=_View Log}" Margin="10,0,10,0"/>
```