# Assign Short-cut Key(s) to button in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using button in one of my wpf window. I am binding my custom routed UI command to the button.

```
public static readonly RoutedUICommand DeleteRow = new RoutedUICommand("Delete Row", "Delete Row", typeof(TestDataView));
```

I want to assign Delete key as a short-cut. How can I achieve it? Please guide me. Do let me know if you need any other information about this question.

Regards,
Priyank

Comment: a way to do it...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246134/assign-short-cut-key-to-a-button-wpf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
 DeleteRow.InputGestures.Add(new KeyGesture(Key.Delete));
```

Comment: Hi ionden, thanks for the inputs. Do I have to mention the input bindings in xaml too???