# Add Short Cut Key to button

Tags: c#, wpf

How Can I Add Short Cut Key To button in wpf?
I have three window with New Button and i want to add Ctrl+N or etc short cut to all of them.

Comment: You can use underscore `_` in button contents and it will trigger with `Alt` key. also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246134/assign-short-cut-key-to-a-button-wpf

Comment: This similar question might be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612966/keyboard-events-in-a-wpf-mvvm-application

Answer (score 2):

Here is a great tutorial for this : https://web.archive.org/web/20150430045153/http://tech.pro:80/tutorial/839/wpf-tutorial-command-bindings-and-custom-commands

Sample (taken from link above)

```
<Window x:Class="CustomCommandTest.CommandWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Custom Command Test" Height="300" Width="300">

  <Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="Help" 
        CanExecute="HelpCanExecute"
        Executed="HelpExecuted" />
  </Window.CommandBindings>

  <Window.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="Help" Key="H" Modifiers="Ctrl"/>
    <MouseBinding Command="Help" MouseAction="LeftDoubleClick" />
  </Window.InputBindings>

  <StackPanel>
    <Button Command="Help" Content="Help Command Button" />
    <Button Content="My Command" x:Name="MyCommandButton" />
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: How can I add to multiple window?

Comment: @AComputert: write a subclass which is inherited from Window or UserControl. Then implement these in that `YourWindow` and then use it instead of any window you want.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it as following method too. in form write method indicating short cut keys.

```
private void shortcutKey_Click(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Key == Key.N) && (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl)))
        ProjMnuBtn_AddProj_Click(null, null);
}
```

then in xaml file you need to set it as follows:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Width="1280" Height="920" KeyUp="shortcutKey_Click">

</Window>
```

Comment: How can I  add to multiple window?

Comment: in this method you have to write this code in each window