# WPF Bind button to key pressed

Tags: c#, wpf

I have not done WPF development before.

I am creating a calculator. I want the "one" button to be bound to the keyboard key "1".
So the click function of my button must execute when the keyboard key "1" is pressed.

Please advise on how to do this>

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246134/assign-short-cut-key-to-a-button-wpf

Answer (score 3):

use this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keygesture.aspx

```
<Window.InputBindings>
  <KeyBinding Command="{Binding MyCommand}"
              Gesture="CTRL+R" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```