# WPF – How to set shortcut for custom button (image and TextBlock)

Tags: wpf, keyboard-shortcuts

I Have a little WPF window that contains 3 buttons with image and TextBlock like this :

```
<Button x:Name="cmdPrint" Margin="5" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2" 
                    ToolTip="Print a simulation"
                     MouseMove="MouseMouveHandler"
                    Click="ButtonClickHandler" Height="36">
 <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
       <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

     <Image Source="images\print.png" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"  
      Margin="2"/>

      <TextBlock Text="_Print" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="DarkBlue" 
      VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2"/>
 </Grid>

</Button>
```

As you can see , the button is customized, so, the following code doesn’t work :

```
<Button Name="cmdPrint " Content="_Print"></Button>
```

Is it possible  to Fire Print button when i Press ‘P’ key ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You must begin to accept the answers, at least sometimes.

Comment: Move the code you want to execute in print button to a method.In keydown event check whether pressed key is "P". If so, call the method .

Comment: Similar question [Assign Short Cut Key to a button + WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246134/assign-short-cut-key-to-a-button-wpf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use label instead of text block will work for you

> ```
>                 Click="ButtonClickHandler" Height="36" >
>             <Grid>
>                 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
>                     <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
>                     <ColumnDefinition Width="70"/>
>                 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
>
>                 <Image  Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"  
>                        Margin="2"/>
>
>                  <Label Content="_Print" Grid.Column="1" Foreground="DarkBlue" 
>                         VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2" />
>
>
>             </Grid>
>
>         </Button>
> ```

Comment: It works fine...But when window starts, Labels aren't underlined until i press Alt, however shortcuts work well, it is not a  problem. Thank you very much.