# Clicking of a button with the help of 'A' key from keyboard in c#

Tags: c#

Assume that i am creating a button for counter application, here i need to click the button with the help of a keyboard key instead of mouse click. Anyone can help with that function.

Comment: is that WPF or Winforms?

Comment: Why not separate the shared logic of button click/key press into its own method, and call that method from both?

Comment: When the button has the focus the space bar will activate it, or did you want specific use of 'A'? You should really provide examples of the code you have already tried.

Comment: is button clicking important.. you can always call logic to be performed on key press .

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on windows app
You should add an event to the form, where the user is expected to press the key
Right click on the  object that should receive the key press (the body of the form)
Go to properties page
Click on the thunder icon (Events)
Go to the KEY section
Double click on Key Down
Write the following:

```
if (e.KeyValue == 65) MessageBox.Show("You clicked the letter A. Code of B is 66, and so on");
```

To discover the KeyValue of the key pressed by the user:

```
MessageBox.Show(e.KeyValue.ToString());
```

Comment: Are you sure this is what OP wants?  This takes a lot of assumptions...

Comment: What's a windows app? Like windows 8 metro app?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Alt + A instead of button , which is access key for your button you can refer to the https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms178233.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As said in another answer Alt + the key is a button shortcut. One way in WinForms is to stick & in front of the character in the button text that you want to use to activate the button. E.g. if the button text is "ABC", change it to "&ABC". Then Alt-A can be used to activate the button. & is how button shortcuts are defined.

For WPF use AccessText or, without using Alt, key bindings: [Assign Short Cut Key to a button in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3246134/)